# How can i decode the HTML Code in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using below code to Decode the HTML code:

```
-(NSString *)decodeString:(NSString *)str 
{ 
    // To Remove the HTML code to Nsstring 
    NSData *stringData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType}; NSAttributedString *decodedString; 
    decodedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:stringData options:options documentAttributes:NULL error:NULL]; 
    return decodedString.string; 

}
```

This code takes a long time to decode the string. So is there is any other way to decode the HTML code?

I don’t want to use the async OR GCD, because I am using this code at the time of stoaring the records in the database.

So please suggest some alternative. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing records in the database then you can use background queue with and Loader or HUD.Because as much data you will decode it will take more time.So in my opinion please make it in background

Comment: Thanks for a quick Reply…. I have implemented the above solution in my code…however it takes a same time to decode the HTML code… is there is any other solution that will decode the HTML in faster way ?

Comment: If you are storing records in the database then you can use background queue with and Loader or HUD.Because as much data you will decode it will take more time.So in my opinion please make it in background